# Getting string instead of list when trying to get value of JSON response

Tags: python, django

I have the following JSON response:

```
{"response": [100, {"name": "Bill"}, {"name": "John"}]}
```

All I need is to iterate through the list. 
So my plan is to get the list first and then iterate through it. 
But when I tried to get the list with

```
list_dict.json().get("response")
```

I got the string:

```
100{"name": "Bill"}{"name": "John"}
```

How could I get the list?

UPDATE: Here is the related code views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from lib.api import Api
import requests, json

def verify(request):
    api = Api(access_token=access_token)
    list_dict = api.get_all(owner_id=owner_id)
    result = list_dict.json().get("response")
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

Here is the api.py

```
import requests
class Api:
    def __init__(self, access_token='', **kwargs):
        self.access_token = access_token

    def get_all(self, owner_id=''):
        api_url_template = 'http://api.example.com/method/get.All?owner_id={0}&access_token={1}'
        api_url = api_url_template.format(owner_id, self.access_token)
        response = requests.get(api_url)
        return response
```

Comment: What type is the return result from `json()`?

Comment: http://ideone.com/7h8iiT  ... seems to work fine

Comment: What is `list_dict`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman list_dict is just a variable which stores the response

Comment: But it apparently has a `json()` method. Where from?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I use requests.get() in order to get the response

Comment: You'll probably get an answer in 30 seconds if you post all the related code instead of forcing us to guess at what list_dict is

Comment: And how you're printing the "string".

Comment: @Keatinge sorry my fault, I updated the question

Comment: @DanielRoseman i've just added the code snippet to the original question, i use HttpResponse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just the result of passing a list to HttpResponse. If you want to see the full response as a string, pass it as a string:

```
return HttpResponse(str(result))
```

Of course, to use it as a list within your code you don't need to convert it to a string, you can just use it as is.